# How do I calculate the logarithm in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to calculate the natural logarithm.

In KDB, I type:

```
log(11%10) - log(9%10)
```

which gives a result `0.1867787`

The problem is, this result is wrong. It should return `0.2006707`. This answer is confirmed with Wolfram Alpha, and just by taking `log(11%9)` in KDB (via rules of logarithms).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use ( ) for arguments to a function, you use [ ], so this works:

```
q)log[11%10] - log[9%10]
0.2006707
```

q is evaluated right-to-left, and for single argument functions, you don't even need to use [ ]. So

```
log[9%10]
```

is equivalent to

```
log 9%10
```

With all that in mind, your original attempt is equivalent to

```
log[(11%10) - log[9%10]]
```

Comment: Oh! I forgot I was in K-land! Thank you! :) Out of curiosity then, what exactly did I calculate, as it didn't error out?